# How to handle Hibernate connections

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I'm new to Hibernate. I've created the SessionFactory and obtaining the Session like below. And I'm using c3p0 connection provider

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    try {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            Configuration configuration = loadDBConfiguration();
            if (configuration != null) {
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
            } else {
                log.info("---- Configuration failed ----");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.info("---- Initial SessionFactory creation failed ----");
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    try {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        entityManagerFactory = session.getEntityManagerFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    return entityManagerFactory;
}

public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    try {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = getEntityManagerFactory();
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And i'm confused with below things.

1. Should i close the connection after commit(), or c3p0 connection provider will close after commit().
2. Shall i call getEntityManager() on each request or should i use like singleton
3. If i'm used as singleton, then does it affect any parallel transaction.begin() or transaction.commit() if server receives multiple request at same time.
4. Also in singleton the entity still persist in session until it gets closed or clear manually. So what i need to do in this case.

Currently the getEntityManager() gets called in all my EntityManager Classes like UserManager, AccountsManager. After some period of time in RDS it shows like 20connections, even my application not handling any user requests.

Answer (score 0):

You should close your connections. Since your connections are wrapped by the database connection pool, they will not get physically closed, but they will return to the pool. This needs to be done otherwise the connection pool will think the connections are being used and when you hit the pool limit, no new connections will be open.
Keep the session factory as a singleton. You should open a new session for each thread.